# Xamarin and android Permissions for Media and Photos - app crashes in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, android-permissions

I have a rather strange problem that I think is related to permissions.  When I run my app in debug mode, it runs fine but when I run it in release mode it crashes.  The reason I think it may be related to permissions is when I run the app in debug mode, when it is deployed on my test device (my Samsung phone), it asks me to allow access to photos and media.  I've set every permission in the manifest even remotely related to photos and media and have code in `MainActivity.cs` to check for those permissions, yet when I run the app in debug on my phone it STILL asks for permission to access Photos and Media.  I do not see anything in the manifest that specifically mentions photos, and like I stated earlier, I granted access in the manifest to everything that even mentioned "media".  My app also accesses the internet, foreground and other areas that require permissions to be set and I have set those in the manifest and have no issues, just this one.  What am I missing here?

My `MainActivity.cs` code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {


            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ForegroundService) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ForegroundService }, 1);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this,Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet }, 1);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this,Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState }, 1);
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessMediaLocation) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessMediaLocation }, 1);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.MediaContentControl) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.MediaContentControl }, 1);
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera }, 1);
            }
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.logon);
            RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            Button MyButton_Submit = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.button_submit);
            aTextboxUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.aTextboxUsername);
            aTextboxPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.aTextboxPassword);
            InputMethodManager board = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            board.HideSoftInputFromWindow(aTextboxUsername.WindowToken, 0);

            Button MyButton_CreateAccount = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.button_createaccount);
            MyButton_CreateAccount.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.YellowGreen);

            MyButton_Submit.Click += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

                ProgressBarHandler myprogressbar = new ProgressBarHandler(this);
                myprogressbar.show();

                var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(async delegate
                {
                    await SignOn(myprogressbar);
                    resetEvent.Set();

                }));
                thread.Start();

                await Task.Run(() => resetEvent.WaitOne());

                while (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }

                myprogressbar.hide();

                if (myprogressbar.ErrorMesage != null)
                {
                    showMessage(myprogressbar.ErrorMesage);
                }
            };

            MyButton_CreateAccount.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CreateAccount));
                Bundle bundlee = new Bundle();
                intent.PutExtra("TheBundle", bundlee);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.LogError("An error occured in MainActivity.cs, the error is: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

*** Update ***

This is what I see in the device log:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
06-24 08:58:00.417  Samsung SM-G973U    Warning 1141    ContextImpl Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1162 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner:579 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication:443 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:12323 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash:12258 
  Force finishing activity My.App/crc64a23c41873b6fbff5.MainActivity
06-24 08:58:00.417  Samsung SM-G973U    Info    2468    dumpstate   skip_space_check : 0
06-24 08:58:00.417  Samsung SM-G973U    Info    2468    dumpstate   skeymaster_only: 0, keystore_only: 0
06-24 08:58:00.417  Samsung SM-G973U    Info    2468    dumpstate   shutdown_broadcast: 0, shutdown_delay: 0
06-24 08:58:00.417  Samsung SM-G973U    Info    2468    dumpstate   sec_mode : 1 dump_flags : 247031436, booting_delay : 0 booting_enospc : 0 sys_rescue : 0 sys_error : 0 sys_native : 0 sys_watchdog : 0 app_error : 1 app_native : 0 app_anr : 0
06-24 08:58:00.416  Samsung SM-G973U    Info    2468    dumpstate   do_zip_file: 1 do_vibrate: 0 use_socket: 0 use_control_socket: 0 do_screenshot: 0 is_remote_mode: 0 show_header_only: 0 do_start_service: 0 telephony_only: 0 wifi_only: 0 do_progress_updates: 0 fd: 10 bugreport_mode: BUGREPORT_A_ERROR dumpstate_hal_mode: DEFAULT limited_only: 0 args: 
06-24 08:58:00.416  Samsung SM-G973U    Warning 1141    ActivityManager crash : My.App,10511
```

Comment: if you comment out the permission check does it do the same thing ? Also I assume you have things set correct in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Good question - so I commented out the permission check code and the "Allow app to access photos and media" prompt went away.  I have no idea why that would happen, but it did.  I'm totally baffled.  But, the app still crashes in release mode which is the bigger concern, I just thought it was related to permission mostly because I had this problem in an earlier version of the same app.  Now I have no idea, but still think maybe permissions.

Comment: what causes the crash?  Does your exception handler catch it?  Have you tried using AppCenter or some other crash reporting tool?  Have you looked at the device logs?

Comment: Nothing was captured by the try catch, neither was there anything in the device logs :(

Comment: I added the device log messages I get on the crash.  Not very informative, of course.  :(

Comment: What happens if you run it release mode in visual studio and you have the exception settings check all for Common Language Runtime Exceptions ? You will get all kinds of exceptions on startup so beware. But you might find one that has something to do with permissions.

Comment: @Micah Armantrout Where would I find that setting? Tools->Options?

Comment: @Micah Armantrout Nevermind, I found it.  It's already set on.

Comment: so does that mean it doesn't throw anything ?

Comment: @Micah Armantrout I figured it out, adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after an 2 day agonizing process I (apparently) figured it out.

I turned off (unchecked) `Enable Multi-Dex` in Project->Properties->Android Options

The app now runs in Release mode with no issues.